# how to get productId in sign up or sign in page when full page cache on in magento2?

Tags: magento2, catalog, full-page-cache

I want to redirect page if customer come from product page ->sign up page i want redirect them after sign up on product page.

But i am not getting product id on that page if full page cache is on in magento2.

> I have created loginpost observer for redirecting page back where before come.
>   I am not getting product_id when full page cache is on 
>   **$product_id = $this->_catalogSession->getData('productId');**// i am talking about this line

```
<?php

namespace Tatva\Customer\Observer;

  use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
  use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
  use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
  use Tatva\Subscription\Model\Subscription;

  class LoginpostObserver implements ObserverInterface{

/**
 * [$_subscription]
 * @var [\Tatva\Subscription\Model\Subscription;]
 */
protected $_subscription;


/**
 * [$_customerSession ]
 * @var [\Magento\Customer\Model\Session]
 */
protected $_customerSession;

/**
 * [$_urlInterface ]
 * @var [\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface]
 */
protected $_urlInterface;

/**
 * [$_catalogSession to get productid]
 * @var [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Session]
 */
protected $_catalogSession;



public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    Subscription $subscription,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
)
{
    $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;        
    $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;        
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_subscription = $subscription;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}

/**
 * @param Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $Observer)
{
    // Check if customer is redirected by product page then process accordingly

    **$product_id = $this->_catalogSession->getData('productId');**

    if($product_id > 0)
    {
        $productCanBeDownloaded = $this->_subscription->productCanBeDownloaded($product_id);


        if($productCanBeDownloaded == 2)
        {
            $pricingUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('pricing');
            $this->_customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($pricingUrl);
        }
        elseif ($productCanBeDownloaded == 3) 
        {
            $acc_subscription_list_url = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('subscription/index/list');
            $this->_customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($acc_subscription_list_url);
        }
        else{
            $url=$this->_productRepository->getById($product_id)->getProductUrl();
            $this->_customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($url);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please upload your file code.

Comment: @RohanHapani i have updated code

Comment: check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this event :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_front_send_response_before">
        <observer name="vendor_module" instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Observer" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: what is the meaning of event.xml code here?

Comment: some events which is related to predispatch is cached when FPC is on. So you cannot rely on it. You need to catch controller_front_send_response_before. It is fired even when FPC is on.

Comment: But then how can i get after customer login?

Comment: It's work for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try Plugin (instead of Observer) to resolve the issue as described below.

**step 1)** create **di.xml** under ***/app/code/Tatva/Customer/etc/***

File: **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
     <plugin name="subscription_loginpostplugin" type="\Tatva\Customer\Model\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
   </type>
</config>
```

**step 2**: Craete **LoginPostPlugin.php** under ***/app/code/Tatva/Customer/Model/Plugin/***

File : **LoginPostPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Tatva\Customer\Model\Plugin;


  use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
  use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
  use Tatva\Subscription\Model\Subscription;

class LoginPostPlugin
{


   /**
 * [$_subscription]
 * @var [\Tatva\Subscription\Model\Subscription;]
 */
protected $_subscription;


/**
 * [$_customerSession ]
 * @var [\Magento\Customer\Model\Session]
 */
protected $_customerSession;

/**
 * [$_urlInterface ]
 * @var [\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface]
 */
protected $_urlInterface;

/**
 * [$_catalogSession to get productid]
 * @var [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Session]
 */
protected $_catalogSession;



public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    Subscription $subscription,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
)
{
    $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;        
    $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;        
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_subscription = $subscription;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}

    /**
     * Change redirect after login to home instead of dashboard.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result
     */
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,        
        $result        
        )
    {

        $product_id = $this->_catalogSession->getData('productId');        
        if($product_id > 0)
    {
        $productCanBeDownloaded = $this->_subscription->productCanBeDownloaded($product_id);


        if($productCanBeDownloaded == 2)
        {
            $pricingUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('pricing');            
            $result->setPath($pricingUrl);
        }
        elseif ($productCanBeDownloaded == 3) 
        {
            $acc_subscription_list_url = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('subscription/index/list');            
            $result->setPath($acc_subscription_list_url);
        }
        else{
            $url=$this->_productRepository->getById($product_id)->getProductUrl();            
            $result->setPath($url);
        }
    }        

    return $result;
 }

}
```

step 3: Run below command

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo chmod -Rv 777 pub var generated
```

Comment: Not working have tried..